# VBA: How to wait until the excel download is complete?

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I have a macro which navigates to a series of web pages, downloads an excel from those pages, and then merges the data onto the open workbook. However, my code fails because it cannot find the newly downloaded workbook. When i step through the code, there is no problem. Presumably my code continues to run but as the newly downloaded workbook is not open yet, it fails.

I have tried to create a loop which waits until the downloaded workbook opens, but it seems that the workbook cannot open while the loop is running.

How can I 'wait' within my code until the workbook is open and my code can proceed?
any inputs appreciated, thank you!

```
appIE.document.getElementById("_id3805:_id3806:0:_id4177").Click 'click website download button
Dim o As IUIAutomation
Dim e As IUIAutomationElement, download_check As IUIAutomationElement
Set o = New CUIAutomation
Dim h As LongLong
h = appIE.Hwnd
h = FindWindowEx(h, 0, "Frame Notification Bar", vbNullString)
If h = 0 Then Exit Sub
Set e = o.ElementFromHandle(ByVal h)
Dim iCnd As IUIAutomationCondition
Set iCnd = o.CreatePropertyCondition(UIA_NamePropertyId, "Open")
Dim Button As IUIAutomationElement
Set Button = e.FindFirst(TreeScope_Subtree, iCnd)
Dim InvokePattern As IUIAutomationInvokePattern
Set InvokePattern = Button.GetCurrentPattern(UIA_InvokePatternId)
InvokePattern.Invoke


Debug.Print "Download Successful, Click OK"

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
DoEvents
' This part searching active workbook
Dim xWBName As String
Dim GetBook As String
Dim xWb As Workbook

Do Until Application.Workbooks.Count > 1
'    'I am waiting for something to happen
    DoEvents
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Sleep 1000
Loop

For Each xWb In Application.Workbooks
    'xWBName = xWb.Name 'xWBName & xWb.Name & vbCrLf
    DoEvents
    If InStr(xWb.Name, "Data") Then
     GetBook = xWb.Name
    End If
Next
DoEvents
'Activate the required workbook
**Set wb2 = Workbooks(GetBook)**
```

Comment: From your code it is not clear how you open the specific downloaded file as you don't know its name. Also it is not clear why you use application.wait and sleep() both together. You should use any one of it. Try to provide the detailed information may help us to understand the issue in better way.

Comment: hihi, the code above is what i use to click and then select the "open" option when the internet explorer 'download notification frame' is triggered (I do not know the name of the file being opened). I have tried using: doevents, application.wait and sleep() in my loop as i hoped that one of them would 'release' vba process and allow the excel to open but none of the methods is having this effect. it seems that the downloaded excel cannot open while the macro is running regardless of this loop. the file opens only when i exit the macro.

Comment: As you are opening the file manually, VBA code will not have control on that file before it get opened and assigned to any object in VBA code. So it does not looks a proper approach for handling this issue. If possible for you than you can divide your code in 2 subs and run them when you need it. by this way, you not need to wait for that file. you can run the other sub after file get downloaded and opened.

Comment: Everything happens within vba, including opening the file.

Comment: You said that you are clicking the open option to open the file. which is manual operation.

Comment: 'Click' is an action i perform in vba, it is an automated action: appIE.document.getElementById("_id3805:_id3806:0:_id4177").Click

Comment: Try to put your For each loop for checking the file name inside your do loop and try to check for files after waiting for 1 second. If file found then exit the loop otherwise again wait for 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach with sleep and doEvents is a good way to solve it. Bevore opening the downloaded workbook, check in your sleep loop if it exists, then exit the loop.

```
If Dir(pathToFile) <> "" Then
    'File has been found
end if
```

EDIT:
I dont see the part where you are trying to open the file.
The order in which things should happen in your case is:
1. Download file
2. Waiting-loop in which you check if the file has been downloaded
3. Open file

the sleep loop could look something like this:

```
'Download the file here

dim fileFound as boolean
while not fileFound
    sleep(1000)
    DoEvents
    If Dir(pathToFile) <> "" Then
        fileFound = true
    end if
wend

'Open the file here
```

Comment: hihi. Currently, my code gets stuck in the sleep/doevents loop. It seems that while the code is looping, excel isnt able to open the download. Therefore, i dont think there is a problem with the loop condition, just the way i am 'waiting'. In addition, i dont always know the exact naming of the file i am downloading